# Merge Request of only desired commits

Tags: git, git-merge

My manager wants me to send atomic merge requests in order to follow changes easily. I want to implement 2 feature, `feature1` and `feature2` which are not completely independent from each other. Let say I write a class definition and some methods to it in `feature1` and I add some other methods to same class in `feature2`.

My idea was that I create a branch `X` from `master` branch and implement `feature1`. I commit and push and send my merge request. For the `feature2`, I create another branch `Y` from branch `X` so that it includes `feature1`. I implement `feature2` commit, push and send merge request.

If my manager does not accept first merge request before I implement `feature2`, second merge request includes not only `feature2` but also `feature1`. And this makes following the changes harder.

I want only `feature2` in my second merge request. How to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Can't you create feature2 branch which is independent of feature1 so that you'll have to PR request feature1 and feature2 against branch X. And no matter which one gets approved first both can be merged easily.

Comment: when i create new branch from `master` for feature2 and PR feature1, it still brings feature1 in the merge request of feature2. I only want feature2 while merging feature2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a bogus merge request from `Y` to `X` instead of `master`. Then it would show only feature2 implementation.
After `X` is merged you edit the merge request and change target to `master`.

Comment: This seems to be a valid solution until when  a feedback arrives to me about feature1 and I update X before the merge, then there exists some conflicts. For small changes in the branch it is easy to resolve these conflict, but I do not know in the future if these conflicts would be a big trouble for me. Do you have any comment for this issue?

Comment: You resolve them as usual, by merging X into Y, or by rebasing Y to the new X top. When this results in conflicts they seem to be valid, you would have to fix them anyway.